# How to write a Linq to SQL join query with parameter which returns columns from both table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I can't figure out how to write this query in Linq:

```
select ic.icCategory, d.domHosting, d.domCode  
  from Domains d join Image_Categories ic 
    on ( d.domCode = ic.icDomainCode )
      where d.domCode = 'code'
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var result =
    from d in dbContext.Domains
    join ic in dbContext.Image_Categories on d.domCode equals ic.icDomainCode
    where d.domCode == 'code'
    select new { ic.icCategory, d.domHosting, d.domCode }
```

There is some more information about the Query Expression Syntax Join Operators and some examples here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896266.aspx

Answer (score 2):

if you have proper foreign key constraints in your database, there is no need to do all the plumbing on the join yourself. linq-sql creates these also in your classes! That is the beauty of an orm, otherwise you are just writing sql in a different syntax.

You can do

```
Var x = from i in db.Image_categoriees
    Where i.domain.domcode == 'code'
    Select new { i.icCategory, i.domain.domcode, i.domain.domhosting}
```

Comment: Thx. I encourage you to switch to the more OO side, i think it is easier to read and maintain...

Answer (score 0):

```
from Domains d join Image_Categories ic  on d.domCode equals ic.icDomainCode
where d.domCode = 'code'
select ic.icCategory, d.domHosting, d.domCode
```

Comment: -1 This code won't compile. If you make the necessary corrections I will rescind the downvote.

Comment: Keep your stupid downvote.  It's close enough to clarify the proper functionality.  If really think that justifies a downvote, so be it.